# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' Error while using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup and was trying to scrape the [DevCommunity](https://www.dev.to) website. But I'm getting the first article then a *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'* error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

try:
    
    source = requests.get('https://www.dev.to')
    source.raise_for_status()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')
    
    articles = soup.find_all( class_="crayons-story")
    for x in articles:
        title = x.find(class_="crayons-story__title")
        title_text = title.text
        print(title_text)
except Exception as e :
    print(e)
```

Comment: Have you checked what's in `source.text`?

Comment: Yes it is the whole html document.

Comment: Don't catch the exception and you'll get a better error message telling you what line of code failed and what it was trying to use which was actually `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from external URL via Javascript. So `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. To simulate this Ajax requests you can use this example:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://dev.to/search/feed_content'

params = {
    "per_page": "15",
    "page": 1,
    "sort_by": "hotness_score",
    "sort_direction": "desc",
    "approved": "",
    "class_name": "Article",
}

for params['page'] in range(1, 3):    # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    for r in data['result']:
        print(r['title'])
```

Prints:

```
Kubernetes Architectural Overview
Revolutionizing Software Engineering: Embracing the Power of AI
Data Structures in C# Part 3: HashSets
Extracting Class Methods: How To Derive an Interface From a Class
SVG Image optimisations and caching from s3
NodeJS Basics
Spring REST working with enums
Persisting non-primitive types in JPA
Importing CSV to AGE
SQL Project Planning | HackerRank | MSSQL
Wordpress Booking Plugins
GitHub Traffic Checker
HOW THE PROVIDER DESIGN PATTERN
Wordpress Image Optimization Plugins
Wordpress Plugins that are important
CSS positioning with an example
100 DAYS - DAY 22
Different methods of API(Application Program Interface ) in Javasript
Javascript Array Methods
[Typia] I made realtime demo site of 20,000x faster validation (+200x faster JSON stringify)
Git Cheat sheet
Setting Up Your Next Project
3 Foolproof Strategies for Staying Organized in Code
Python Threading: A Comprehensive Guide to Multithreading in Python
This is my first post.
Everything you need to know about DOM in Javascript
Javascript Basics
Form input fields in HTML
GSoC Week 2-3 Update
JavaScript vs React
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple test if you put into the console of your browser on that website:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.crayons-story').length) // output: 51
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.crayons-story .crayons-story__title').length) // output: 50
```

Therefore, there must be one `.crayons-story` without a `crayons-story__title` child. So, to keep it simple, you can just skip it by checking `if title == None:`, or use Andrej Kesely's anwser.